# Why do my console doesn't respond in this code? Dart

Tags: dart, input, console

The console does not respond to this code. Here I tried to use stdout.write(), instead of print().
'For your convenience, I use Microsoft VS code.'

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {

  

  stdout.write('Enter your name:');
  String name = stdin.readLineSync();   //Read name

  stdout.write('Enter your age:');      
  int age = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync());   //Read age as int

  stdout.write('You are $age and your name is $name');

}
```

Comment: When you say "not respond" what does that mean? Does it not output anything? Or does it not take the input after you write it after you click "enter"?

Comment: `stdout.write` is not what you want. You need to use `print(myTextStatement)`. This should print something. Are you receiving any errors?

Comment: @julemand101   In  VS code I see output as  ''Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:65323/BV2ukCkUinE=/ws'' -----Output------and then Exited. Here in this code I see  only ''Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:65323/BV2ukCkUinE=/ws''

Comment: @SiddharthaPandey Does you program print anything if you change it to a simple `print('Hello World')`?

Comment: @julemand101 while using 'print' instead of stdout.write, it give the very first statement 'Enter your name:' only. I could not enter any value in the output console. Moreover, I tried this code in dartpad, it gives error as unsupported 'dart:io'; . I think there is another library for user input. Which may be recently updated that I'm unknown about.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the vs code console doesn't allow input.

You need to create a launch config and set console to terminal.